# Microsoft Graph API, Folder resource type

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, directory-structure

As per the Microsoft document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/folder?view=graph-rest-1.0 ,

this `Folder` resource type has properties `childCount` and `view`.

Does the `childCount` include both files and folders count or only files/folders count?

If it returns both Files and Folders Count, Is there any way that I get only the files count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childCount` property on `folder` resource type includes both files and folders count.

```
childCount = foldersCount + filesCount
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! Is there any way we can get the file and folder count separately?

Comment: @Vinoth.R There is no property for foldersCount or filesCount on the folder resource type. The endpoint which returns a collection of DriveItems in the children relationship of a DriveItem does not support filtering, so it's not possible to filter only child folders or child files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters

Comment: In the API response, we do get File Resource Type, from which we can say if it is a file or not, My code will go through each and every folder and sub-folder and collect the data, If I add a flag or something to indicate it as a file, then I think we can figure out a way to separate files and folder.

File Resource Type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/file?view=graph-rest-1.0 

Anyways thanks for the help @user2250152